# How to run a simple Docker container when an EC2 is launched in an AWS auto-scaling group?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ec2, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

```
$ terraform version
Terraform v0.14.4
```

I'm using Terraform to create an AWS autoscaling group, and it successfully launches an EC2 via a launch template, also created by the same Terraform plan. I added the following `user_data` definition in the launch template. The AMI I'm using already has Docker configured, and has the Docker image that I need.

```
user_data = filebase64("${path.module/docker_run.sh}")
```

and the `docker_run.sh` file contains simple

```
docker run -p 80:3000 -d 1234567890.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/node-app:latest
```

However, when I ssh to the EC2 instance, the container is NOT running. What am I missing?

**Update:**
Per Marcin's comment, I see the following in `in /var/log/cloud-init-output.log`

```
Jan 11 22:11:45 cloud-init[3871]: __init__.py[WARNING]: Unhandled non-multipart (text/x-not-multipart) userdata: 'docker run -p 80:3000 -d...'
```

Comment: Can you clarify what instance? Have you installed and configured docker on it?

Comment: @Marcin, what do you mean "what instance?" It's an EC2 instance, t2.micro, created by an autoscaling group. Yes I can ssh to the instance and execute `docker ...` commands, including of course my `docker run...` command.

Comment: Standard Amazon Linux 2 instance does not have docker pre-installed. Thus its not clear what instance are you using that has docker build-in? Also, have you checked `/var/log/cloud-init-output.log` for UserData errors?

Comment: @Marcin, I've configured Docker in the AMI that I used. Like I said, I can simply ssh into the EC2 instance and execute `docker...` commands.

Comment: I see `Jan 11 22:11:45 cloud-init[3871]: __init__.py[WARNING]: Unhandled non-multipart (text/x-not-multipart) userdata: 'docker run -p 80:3000 -d...'` in `/var/log/cloud-init-output.log`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [AWS docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/user-data.html#user-data-shell-scripts) and what you've posted the likely reason is that you are missing `/bin/bash` in your `docker_run.sh`:

> User data shell scripts **must start** with the #! characters and the path to the interpreter you want to read the script (commonly /bin/bash).

Thus your `docker_run.sh` should be:

```
#!/bin/bash
docker run -p 80:3000 -d 1234567890.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/node-app:latest
```

If this still fails, please check `/var/log/cloud-init-output.log` on the instance for errors.

Comment: Marcin, you da man! That was too obvious that I missed it. Thanks!

Comment: @ChrisF No problem. I also did not notice this at first:-)